# Usando máscara jquery em campo no ASP.net Core MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, input-mask

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de CRM com C# asp.net core com MySQL e já estou com banco pronto e tudo certinho e fiz o formulário de cadastro de cliente e estou na parte de validações agora.

Quero colocar máscara para `CPF/CNPJ`, `telefone`, `cep` e tudo mais e baixei no gerenciador de pacotes [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) o `jQuery Input Mask` como na imagem:

> [image: https://prnt.sc/vuluei]

Estou usando esse [tutorial do Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/15/12/mvc_mask1.htm), mas é para ASP NET MVC e ele pede o seguinte **Abra a pasta `App_Start` e inclua o script abaixo no final do arquivo BundleConfig.cs :**, mas o meu projeto é ASPNET CORE e não tem o `bundleconfig.cs`.

Gostaria de saber se essa é a melhor forma de colocar máscara e como proceder para colocar no ASPNET CORE

<sup>**Observação:** tentei fazer referencia no Layout da pasta `shared` e usar a máscara e dá erro.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira da instalação não é feita ainda para ASPNET CORE, então, siga esses passos:

- Baixe o pacote no próprio site [ [download](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/releases/tag/5.0.5) ] :
- Descompacte em algum diretório e busque a pasta `dist/` que tem o código [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) `jquery.inputmask.js`.
- Adicione esse arquivo dentro da pasta do seu projeto ASPNET CORE `wwwroot/js/`
- Dentro da pasta do seu projeto `shared` tem o seu layout com o nome `_Layout.cshtml` no final desse arquivo a referencia desse arquivo, ***exemplo***:

  ```
  <script src="~/js/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
  ```

para utilizar faça como no exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#data").inputmask('99/99/9999');
  $("#cpf").inputmask('999.999.999-99');
  $("#cnpj").inputmask('99.999.999/9999-99');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/5.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="data" /><br />
<input type="text" id="cpf" /><br />
<input type="text" id="cnpj" /><br />
```

---

Comment: Muito muito muito obrigado!

Comment: Se for util vote como solução da sua pergunta! @VitorLima

Comment: Não sei votar como solução, estou tentando aqui.